# sql order by multiple columns with nulls

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a resultes set that looks like the following in a table var(sorry for the poor formatting):

```
RootID | RootName | ChildId | ChildName

1      |  Bob     |  null   |   null   

1      |  null    |    4    |   Tim

1      |  null    |    6    |   Cindy

2      |  Alice   |  null   |   null

2      |  null    |  7      |   Joe 

2      |  null    |    9    |   Jack

3      |  Frank   |  null   |   null 

3      |  null    |   17    |   ken
```

What I would like to do is order them by RootName ASC then ChildName ASC to get them in alphabetical order. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding the question. Are you trying to do something more than what `ORDER BY RootName, ChildName` would give you?

Comment: Whats the issue you are facing? Do you want nulls to appear in certain order?

Comment: if i use order by rootname, child name i end up loosing the parent child structer. all the rootnames are grouped and all the child names are grouped. I would like to first alpha order the rootname column keeping all the rows with the same rootid together, then alpha order the childname keeping the rootid together. or at least sort the rootname by alpha order

Comment: I think it's more of a select/join issue than ordering. How come those rows have a root id but no root name?

Comment: I think im trying to do too many things at once, thanks guys/gals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works for your application, I'd rewrite the query to get rid of the nulls. I can't help but think that

```
RootID | RootName | ChildId | ChildName  
1      |  Bob     |    4    |   Tim  
1      |  Bob     |    6    |   Cindy  
2      |  Alice   |  null   |   Joe   
2      |  Alice   |    4    |   Jack  
3      |  Frank   |    7    |   ken
```

Would be easier to work with. (Uh, that NULL for Alice/Joe is a typo, right?)

Answer (score 1):

Erm... What about this?

```
select * from yourtable order by RootName ASC, ChildName ASC
```

You can use `NULLS LAST` and `NULLS FIRST` (at least in Oracle) to control, where the nulls should be placed in the sorting.

Comment: There are also 'flavors' of NULLS LAST and NULLS FIRST in most other vendor products.

Comment: I thought so, that's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select rec_id,gr_id from jegad order by 1 desc

select isnull(rec_id,'-'),isnull(gr_id,'-') from jegad order by 1 desc
```

**ORDER BY CASE WHEN Col Is NULL Then 1 Else 0 End, Col**